# How do I make my movement AZERTY and QWERTY compatible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the character controller in unity to make the player walk but it's already assigned to WASD but I use an AZERTY keyboard. Is there a way to use both WASD and ZQSD so they both work?

Comment: According to [this Unity forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/new-input-system-which-keyboard-layouts-are-supported.912074/), it should work with either keyboard layout. Does it fail to work when you try it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no it still doesn't work.